# I have Problem in Ajax request in Laravel, post request does not work

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.8

I have a problem in ajax request in laravel 5.8

The problem

POST http://dailyshop.test/ajaxRequest 419 (unknown status)

The route

```
 Route::get('ajaxRequest', 'FrontEndController@ajaxRequest');
```

Ajax Code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('#add-to-cart').click( function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var product_id = $(this).data('id');
            var url = "{{ route('addToCart') }}";

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/ajaxRequest',
                data:{product_id:product_id},
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data.success);
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

The function

```
    public function ajaxRequest() {
         dd('Yes! it working !');
         return view('ajaxRequest'); 
    }
```

Comment: You have a get route, but you are posting data. I think you have to change your route to a post, not get,

Comment: I found the problem
I added this meta tag to the code
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">